# On-click radio button, hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to hide a div when somebody clicks on a radio button on a form (second radio button), but when the click on the first radio button, the div shows back up (a toggle). Here is my working code: http://jsfiddle.net/NKr7M/

Here's the HTML if you would like:

```
<div class="grid howAnswer">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="button-left">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RVmh2rz.png" />

            <input checked="checked" type="radio" id="id_delivery_0" value="chat" name="delivery" onclick="toggle(this)" />
        </div><!-- .button-left -->

        <div class="text-area top-text-area">
            <label for="id_delivery_0">
                AnswerChat By Appointment (Fastest)
            </label>
        </div><!-- .text-area -->
    </div><!-- .col-1 -->

    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="button-left" style="margin-left: 15px;">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8J0SEVa.png" />

            <input type="radio" id="id_delivery_2" value="email" name="delivery" onclick="toggle(this)" />
        </div><!-- .button-left -->

        <div class="text-area bottom-text-area">
            <label for="id_delivery_2">
                AnswerMail ASAP (Within 1-2 days)
            </label>
        </div><!-- .text-area -->
    </div><!-- .col-1 -->
</div><!-- .grid -->

<!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO HIDE -->
<div class="formInput">
    <p>Let's try and hide this div</p>
</div><!-- .formInput -->
```

As well as the CSS:

```
/* General Declarations */
body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

ul li { list-style: none; }

/* Form */
.col-1 li.howDoPadding { padding-bottom: 10px!important; }

.byAppointment { margin: 0 0 -4px 10px;}

.offlineForm .lightBlueText { 
    color: #80A9BD; 
    display: inline;
}

/* Grid */
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.grid.howAnswer > div.col-1 {
    padding-left: 90px;
    position: relative;
}

.grid.howAnswer .button-left {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.button-left img { margin-right: -5px; }

.top-text-area { margin: 15px 0 10px; }

.bottom-text-area { margin: 10px 0 15px; }

.button-left { margin: 10px 0; }

/* Grid Gutters */
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type { padding-right: 0; }

.col-1 { width: 100%; }
```

I'm not very proficient with JavaScript so I would very much appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: where is the js you have attempted in the fiddle?

Comment: I have not attempted any JavaScript solution yet, which is why I didn't include any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NKr7M/6/)**</kbd>

```
$(':radio[name=delivery]').change(function(){ // Or simply: $("[name=delivery]")
    $('.formInput').toggle();
});
```

Comment: what is this selector syntax :radio[name=delivery] I've never seen it.
I had exactly what you have here written up in a fiddle as well, with the difference of that selector.

Comment: @DylanHayes you don't need the tag selector, but if you have more `name=delivery` elements it's just to be more specific http://jsfiddle.net/NKr7M/7/. Also instead of `.formInput` I'd go for an ID.

Comment: That is very wonderful, thank you very much for that. Super simple, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#id_delivery_0").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
       $(".formInput").hide();     
});

$("#id_delivery_2").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
       $(".formInput").show();     
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/NKr7M/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggle()` to do that:

```
$('#id_delivery_0').on("click", function(){
   $(".formInput").hide();
});
$('#id_delivery_2').on("click", function(){
   $(".formInput").show();
});
```

**Working Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/NKr7M/4/

Comment: @CyrilPangilinan I realize that, but I'm sure he can modify the code to work with an individual button.

Comment: @everyone :) Updated ....  because having the OP try something for himself is apparently frowned upon

Comment: Hahaha I love when people delete their comments and then you are left talking to yourself! Priceless!

Comment: @HanletEscaño I find myself doing that far too often .... (please don't remove yours)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the jQuery library is okay since you tagged this with jQuery, so here's  jQuery response:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_delivery_0").click(function() {
        $(".formInput").show();
    });
    $("#id_delivery_2").click(function() {
        $(".formInput").hide();
    });
});
```

Be sure to include the jQuery library as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$('#id_delivery_2').click( function(){
   $('.formInput').hide();
});

$('#id_delivery_0').click( function(){
      $('.formInput').show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/jCuk9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id_delivery_0").on('click',function(){
      $(".formInput").find('p').show();
});

$("#id_delivery_2").on('click',function(){
      $(".formInput").find('p').hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/u6BKu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#button1').click(function(event) { 
     $('#hide').hide();
});

    $('#button2').click(function(event) { 
    $('#hide').show();
    });  
});
```

Comment: You should explain your answer

Comment: when radio button1 click,Demonstrates the jQuery hide() method, hiding the id="hide" elements.and when  radio button2 click,the jQuery show() method visible the id="hide" elements like textfiled,textarea etc.